# Are short-circuits operators allways executed left to right?

Tags: java, short-circuiting

So if code:

```
if(f() && false) {
    // never happens
}
```

Can i be always sure that `f()` will be called and will be never 'optimised-away' by compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `javac` compiler does very little optimisation.

The JIT can optimise code away but in this case you can be sure that `&&` and `||` are always evaluated left to right.

> All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

---

From the JLS.

> 15.7. Evaluation Order
>
> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.
>
> It is recommended that code not rely crucially on this specification. Code is usually clearer when each expression contains at most one side effect, as its outermost operation, and when code does not depend on exactly which exception arises as a consequence of the left-to-right evaluation of expressions.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html

Comment: Could you refer something in java specification or why can i be sure that any java compiler does not come to idea "hey, the right operand is known to be false to compile-time, short-circuits operator is used - so i will just throw it's away"

Comment: The Oracle Java tutorial is not enough? ;) Reading the JLS is often much harder.

Comment: Actually not really enough, because a short-circuits is some special case that could have a special behavior. But now is enough. Thank you:3

Comment: I think the warning about clarity is worth reading again. Just because it works correctly doesn't mean it the clearest way to express something.

Comment: Warning about clarity? Do you mean just don't put function calls in if() statement? Or what warning?

Comment: "It is recommended that code not rely crucially on this specification. Code is usually clearer when each expression contains at most one side effect"